# HTML Video not playing online in chrome but does play locally in chrome

Tags: html, video, element, inspect

```
<html>
   <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video.css">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="banner" class="headerContent">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="headerContent" class="headerContent">
          <video autoplay   id="awsome_video" >
               <source src="http://derrylahan.comze.com/promo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="overlay">
           <h1 id="rowdy"> ROWDY RONDY ROUSEY </h1>
           <a href="test.html" id="enter">ENTER</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

This code works with another mp4 video but not this one any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for any help works fine off line but not on the server im using 000webhost free hosting

when I open inspect element  on chrome and look at network I can see things loading then this message " Failed to write into a temp file: A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed." is displayed at the bottom of the screen

also got this information from inspect element

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: "http://derrylahan.comze.com/UFCR.mp4".
Navigated to http://derrylahan.comze.com/UFCR.mp4

Comment: have you tried hitting that src url directly in the same browser causing this error? what do you get?

Comment: Just get the same "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: "http://derrylahan.comze.com/UFCR.mp4".
Navigated to http://derrylahan.comze.com/UFCR.mp4"   thing benn trying fora good while now but nothing will work

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out

```
<html>
   <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video.css">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="banner" class="headerContent">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="headerContent" class="headerContent">
          <video autoplay   id="awsome_video"  width="320" height="240" controls>

  <source src="http://derrylahan.comze.com/promo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="overlay">
           <h1 id="rowdy"> ROWDY RONDY ROUSEY </h1>
           <a href="test.html" id="enter">ENTER</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still doesnt work the black area of the video shows up but the time is at  0:00 and the bar is empty

Comment: i checked your link of this video, there is no video, please put a real video link

Comment: i provided diffrent code with a webm link cant figure it out

Comment: your this link also does not contain anything

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
   <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video.css">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="banner" class="headerContent">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="headerContent" class="headerContent">
          <video autoplay   id="awsome_video"  width="320" height="240" controls>

  <source src="http://derrylahan.comze.com/big.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
        <div class="overlay">
           <h1 id="rowdy"> ROWDY RONDY ROUSEY </h1>
           <a href="test.html" id="enter">ENTER</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

there is something happening now with a video for testing but the video is at the end when the page loads and doesn't
 play

Comment: this video does not contain anything

Comment: is there a way to convert mp4 to webm